# Use Console2 for Visual Studio debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, console2

Is there a way to use the popular Console2 cmd.exe replacement for Visual Studio debugging? In other words, when I debug a console app under VS, I want it to use Console2 instead of cmd.exe.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: Similar question (answered): [Use custom console for Visual Studio Console Application Debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12605997/1405560)

Answer (score 8):

Interesting question. I looked into it, there are some options but none are pretty.

Console.exe takes arguments, so it's possible to start it with a specific tab and execute an arbitrary process. However, this process will always be run within it's own cmd.exe; for example if your program is c:\my.exe and you launch Console as `console.exe -t tabname -r c:\myexe` Console2 internally calls `CreateProcess( ... cmd.exe c:\my.exe ... )`, as a result you can't even see the output of my.exe. This is easily solved though: launch it as `console.exe -t tabname -r "/k c:\myexe"`: the /k switch makes the cmd.exe stay active and you can see your program's standard output. (I looked through the source but couldn't find a way to 'attach' a tab to a currently running Console instance, so launching with arguments will always create a new instance, not sure this is what you are looking for?

You can easily modify the project's debugging properties to reflect the above:

```
Command: /path/to/console.exe
Command Arguments: -t tabname -r "/k $(TargetPath)"
```

When starting your exe from within VS, it will launch your exe witin a Console session. However the debugging won't work as VS will try to debug console.exe, not my.exe since that is now a different process. Putting a `DebugBreak();` as first line in your exe's main() will sort of solve this, as it will present  you the option to debug your exe. All in all, this may a bit too much of a hassle to achieve what you want, but i don't think there's another way: Console always spawns a new process, so the only way to get it debugged is to attach the debugger to it after that process started.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman [blogged about this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx).

He suggests using this value for *Console Settings > tabs > Main > Shell* :

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

Sadly for me, This does not appear to work for Visual Studio Express 2010, which lacks a *vcvarsall.bat* file.