# How to start a separate Command prompt process and write output to it in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working on project where i want to launch a console window and show some top level output to the client while running my script. I'm following this approach and able to launch the cmd but not able to write into it:

```
   public class ConsoleOutput {

    ProcessStartInfo psi;
    Process p;
    public ConsoleOutput()
    {

        psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
        {
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            Arguments = "/k",
        };
        p = Process.Start(psi);
    }

    public void writeMessage(string msg)
    {


        StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
        sw.WriteLine("prompt " + msg);

    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are getting standardinput and standardoutput correct.  From c# write to standardinput and read from standardoutput.

Comment: snapshot of codes wont help much. Please add your codes here (copy and paste here).

Comment: @Billa i pasted my code please have a look.

Comment: @jdweng yes i'm getting correct stdin and stdout

Comment: Add a Flush().  The write to a stream method in Net uses times and may not send short messages to app.

Comment: You are trying to write to the StandardInput

Comment: @o_weisman yes but i'm assigning the standardinput to the console process only.

Comment: @jdweng i tried using Flush() aswell but still not able to print the  message on the console. Thanks :(

Comment: It's still not the output where you want to write your message. You can also use Console.WriteLine() btw.

Comment: o_weisman : You can't use Console.WriteLine() to write to the standardinput of a process.

Comment: the cmd.exe is not echoing the standard input.  To see the standard input simple in the cmd.exe type >Echo Con.  "Con" is standard input.  See : http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-4-stdin-stdout-stderr.html

Comment: @jdweng That's correct, but based on the description in the O.P's question, I deduce that he/she's trying to write a log to the console's output.

Comment: @o_weisman yes i'm trying to create a log type of thing which will display in separate console rather than visual studio console.

Comment: The O.P needs an app to do take standard-input and display results.  Can be an executable, a bat, or just use Echo Com.  So you could just add a parameter to the process which has "Echo Con"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# debug log console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599107/c-sharp-debug-log-console-app)